# Connecting to HBase in KNIME

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, knime

I am using `KNIME 2.9.4` and I have `HBase` installed (version - `0.94.8`) in a remote Linux server. With the host IP, I am trying to connect to `HBase`.

Here is what I did.

Added the "`hbase-0.94.8.jar`" in the preferences page and the Database driver `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.jdbc.Driver` is loaded properly.

Now, the question is what to keep in the database URL. I kept `10.207.5.21:2181` as `10.207.5.2`1 is my remote ip and `2181` is the zookeeper port.

I am getting the below error:

Error during fetching metadata from database, reason: `org.knime.core.node.InvalidSettingsException: Driver` `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.jdbc.Driver` does not accept URL: `10.207.5.21:2181`

Can someone please let me know, what would have gone wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think zookeeper do not offer a JDBC connection on the management port, so I guess you will need this configuration detail from the admisitrators of the zookeeper cluster (or through this management console). After that you should use the example (http://www.hbql.com/examples/jdbc.html) with that port and IP address.